# Django Admin: edit items on the main admin page, without going inside each item

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

In my Admin page, I want to edit items by selecting from choices under each column, without clicking and going into each item and editing it inside each item's page. I've tried various functions and forms, but still can't find a way to do this.

For example: I have to assign an age range to each item, 0-5, 5-15, 15-25, 25-35 (some items will have multiple choices checked), and I want to assign these values from the main admin page, without going inside each item.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the field has choices, it is easy, use [list_editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) in the ModelAdmin class.

If you want to use something more custom, you should provide a customized form the the rows in the main admin page (by the way, this called "Change List" in Django terms..)

And inside the form, supply choices to the field and event a custom widget.